# Understanding and adding to if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I parse a text (HTML) file for the first GCcode. I have this if sentence that works:

```
$wp = if($html | %{$x -match '\b((GC)[A-Z0-9]+)'}){$matches[1]}
```

The problem is that some time the first value that matches is "gcCode" which is not a valid value. How do I make it search on if the result is "gcCode"

EDIT:

Codes could be GC8DHHW, Gc8BFyD, gcGGNY, gcbbf and any combination og letters and numbers, but always starting with GC, gc, Gc og gC all codes are allowed, just not "gcCode"

The code above works it just needs not to accept "gccode" in any form. If it finds "gccode" it should go on and use the next value that fulfills the REGEX in the current file.

Comment: many PoSh operators have a case-sensitive version ... try using `-cmatch` instead of `-match`. [*grin*]

Comment: The codes I'm looking for come with a unpredictable case so matching only for Capital letters will not help me.

Comment: ah! then you should add a few samples to your Original Post so that folks can see what your pattern needs to be.

Comment: That makes good sense.

How ever the code works with the current REGEX, only problem is that gcCode is valid. And when it occurs it has to take the next match.

Comment: Codes could be GC8DHHW, Gc8BFyD, gcGGNY, gcbbf and any combination og letters and numbers, but always starting with GC, gc, Gc og gC.

Comment: [1] please, please, PLEASE - put all additional info in your Original Post so that others can find it. [2] PLEASE - add two or more FULL SAMPLES to work against since there is no way to test anything without the full line of text to test against.